# Pass struct object from namespace as parameter

Tags: c++, oop

I have problem with passing struct object from specified namespace as parameter in constructor of class. I have my struct:

**settings.h**

```
namespace settings
{
    typedef struct
    {
        volatile uint8_t ddr;
        volatile uint8_t port;
        uint8_t pin1;
        uint8_t pin2;
        uint8_t timerChannel;
        uint8_t showChannel;
        uint8_t sensePin;
        uint16_t resistorValue;
        uint16_t maxCurrent;
    }TServoSettings;
}
```

**settings.cpp**

```
#include "settings.h"

namespace settings
{
     TServoSettings servo1 =
    {
            //Here are some values from preprocessor definies
            SERVO1_DDR,
            SERVO1_PORT,
            SERVO1_PIN1,
            SERVO1_PIN2,
            SERVO1_TIMER_CHANNEL,
            SERVO1_SHOW_CHANNEL,
            SERVO1_SENSE,
            SERVO1_R,
            SERVO1_MAXCURR
    };
}
```

And then I have my example class:

**myclass.h**

```
class CMyclass
{
public:
    CMyclass(TServoSettings * ptr); //<------HOW CAN I PASS HERE CREATED BEFORE OBJECT OF STRUCTURE FROM   NAMESPACE AS A PARAMETER - POINTER??????
    ~CMyclass();
};
```

**myclass.cpp**

```
#include "myclass.h"
CMyclass::CMyclass(TServoSettings * ptr) //HOW PASS ??
{
    //Do some things with this pointer
}

CMyclass::CMyclass()
{
    //Hothing to do here :(
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "settings.h"
#include "myclass.h"

int main()
{
    CMyclass someobject(&settings::servo1);    //AND HOW PASS HERE ?????
}
```

I would like to be glad if someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should qualify your type with namespace name:

```
CMyclass(settings::TServoSettings * ptr); 
         ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Yes, and I get an error : `error: 'settings' has not been declared`

Comment: well, then add `#include "settings.h"` at the top of myclass.h. This error probably shows up only for myclass.cpp.

Comment: also dont forget about include guards: in settings.h and myclass.h

Comment: @drewpol And don't forget to learn some basic C++. Here's a [list of good books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Thanks for Your tips. I added include guards. I included also `#include "settings.h"` in myclass.h. Now in myclass files everythng looks good, but in main file I get error `error: 'servo1' is not a member of 'settings'`. I added includes in main file too.

Comment: sorry for last comment, I have no idea whats wrong now.

Comment: ok, now its clear to me, servo1 is in settings.cpp, so you have no access to it in main.cpp

Comment: you may add `namespace settings { extern TServoSettings servo1; }` to main.cpp to fix this error. Or maybe to settings.h would be a better place.